# ERROR ITMS-9000: Missing or invalid signature. The bundle not signed using Apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

Getting the error from the image when trying to upload my app to app store through application launcher.

**Result** Entitlements.plist: cannot read entitlement data

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use phonegap to build app
2. Create Distribution Certificates .p12 and .provision from Apple Developer website
3. Use https://build.phonegap.com/ to put the app in .ipa
4. Use application launcher to put the .ipa file

Got an error before about the info.plist file, I fixed it by adding the bundle version and bundle version short.

Browsing through the docs I found this workaround, however it did not work.

```
I tried using codesign:
$ unzip /Path/PGBuildApp.ipa 
$ rm -rf Payload/PGBuildApp.app/_CodeSignature/
$ cp /PATH/App.mobileprovision Payload/PGBuildApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
$ codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: NAME" PayLoad/PGBuildApp.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements Entitlements.plist Payload/PGBuildApp.app
```

[image]

Id there any other way I can upload my app to the app store? Perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using codesign or application launcher you can use xCode to build the app. You will be able to build the file in xCode and then everything should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I simply fixed this issue using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html), delete and re-install the certificate.

Open terminal and Unzip the IPA and give the .app file path in the path section.

```
codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' <path>
```

It will show "valid on disk" else "CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED" error message. If else case we delete the certificate and re-install it.

Again check the ipa. It will resolve the issues.